# Rudimentary 3D graphics in C++ .NET

Tags: c++, 3d, directx

I am looking to implement an extremely rudimentary FPS game with extremely rudimentary 3D graphics using C++ .NET and DirectX.

I'm not interested in any third party libraries or anything special like that.

Having never done graphics based programming besides 2D stuff I don't really know where to get started or even how to find the right resources online.

I have a few weeks to build this game so im trying to keep it simple.

Can anyone give me a little guidance on how to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the DirectX SDK and fire up the sample code that puts a rainbow colored 3D shape on screen. Try making it draw more shapes. Try making it so that big shapes can shoot little shapes out of them. Try moving the shapes around. Try moving the camera around.

You can have a fully playable (but weird) game up and running in an evening that way. Later, you can worry about getting more sophisticated one step at a time. For example, keep the game playable while replacing the rainbow colored 3D shape with a mesh that looks like a person or a bullet or a tank.

The key point is to keep the thing playable at all times. That's where the fun is, and it will motivate you to go back again and again to fix "one more detail." It's like the folk story of [Stone Soup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_soup).